# GWT 2.8 cannot get custom linker to work

Tags: java, gwt, linker, gwt-2.8

I have a custom linker to generate a manifest file that used to work fine up to GWT 2.7.  When I changed to GWT 2.8 I noticed it stopped generating the file myapp.manifest.

On module.gwt.xml I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User" />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.core.Core" />

    <source path="client" />
    <source path="shared" />
    <source path="constants" />

    <entry-point class="br.com.universo.client.AppStart" />

    <extend-property name="locale" values="pt" />
    <extend-property name="locale" values="en" />
    <set-property-fallback name="locale" value="en" />

    <define-linker class="br.com.universo.AppManifest"
        name="manifest" />
    <add-linker name="manifest" />


</module>
```

This is the compilation log on 2.7

```
    [INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0:compile (default) @ universo-bootstrap ---
    [INFO] auto discovered modules [br.com.universo.core.appCore, br.com.universo.app]
    [INFO] br.com.universo.core.appCore has no EntryPoint - compilation skipped
    [INFO] Compiling module br.com.universo.app
    [INFO]    Ignored 7 units with compilation errors in first pass.
    [INFO] Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
    [INFO]    Compiling 6 permutations
    [INFO]       Compiling permutation 0...
    [INFO]       Process output
    [INFO]          Compiling
    [INFO]             Compiling permutation 1...
    [INFO]       Compiling permutation 2...
    [INFO]          Compiling
    [INFO]             Compiling permutation 3...
    [INFO]       Compiling permutation 4...
    [INFO]       Compiling permutation 5...
    [INFO]    Compile of permutations succeeded
    [INFO]    Compilation succeeded -- 165.867s
    [INFO] MyApp OffLine Linker started
    [INFO] MyApp OffLine Linker ended
    [INFO] Linking into /universo/universo-bootstrap/target/universo-bootstrap-1.0-SNAPSHOT/app
    [INFO]    Link succeeded
    [INFO]    Linking succeeded -- 1.239s
```

On GWT 2.8 I am using [tbroyer gwt maven archetype modular-webapp](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes/).  The linker class was defined under the client module, but on a package outside

```
<source path="client" />
```

and on compilation log I don't see the lines:

```
[INFO] MyApp OffLine Linker started
[INFO] MyApp OffLine Linker ended
```

which I suppose indicates it is not being called?

```
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:1.0-rc-7:compile (default-compile) @ universo-client ---
[INFO] Compiling module br.com.universo.app
[INFO]    Compiling 9 permutations
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 0...
[INFO]       [WARN] Namespace option is not compatible with CodeSplitter, turning it off.
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 1...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 2...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 3...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 4...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 5...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 6...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 7...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 8...
[INFO]    Compile of permutations succeeded
[INFO]    Compilation succeeded -- 104.171s
[INFO] Linking into /universo/universo-client/target/universo-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT/app
[INFO]    Link succeeded
[INFO]    Linking succeeded -- 1.818s
```

The Linker class AppManifest.java

```
package br.com.universo;

import java.util.Date;

import com.google.gwt.core.ext.LinkerContext;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.TreeLogger;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.linker.AbstractLinker;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.linker.ArtifactSet;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.linker.EmittedArtifact;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.linker.LinkerOrder;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.linker.LinkerOrder.Order;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.linker.Shardable;

@Shardable
@LinkerOrder(Order.POST)
public class AppManifest extends AbstractLinker {

    static final String[] cache = new String[] {
        "# Css"
        , "/css/base.css"
        , "/css/feedback.css"
        , "/css/layout.css"
        , "/css/prettyPhoto.css"
        , "/css/shortcodes.css"
        , "/css/slideshow.css"
        , "/css/style.css"
    }; 

    static final String[] network = new String[] {
        "*"
    };


    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "MyApp OffLine Linker";
    }

     @Override
      public ArtifactSet link(TreeLogger logger, LinkerContext context, ArtifactSet artifacts) throws UnableToCompleteException {
        System.out.println("MyApp OffLine Linker started");
        ArtifactSet artifactset = new ArtifactSet(artifacts);

        StringBuilder builder= new StringBuilder("CACHE MANIFEST\n");
        builder.append("# Cache Version " + new Date() + "\n\n");
        builder.append("CACHE:\n");

        for (String line : cache) {
            builder.append(line + "\n");            
        }
        builder.append("\n\n");

        for(EmittedArtifact emitted: artifacts.find(EmittedArtifact.class))
        {
            if(emitted.getPartialPath().endsWith(".symbolMap"))continue;
            if(emitted.getPartialPath().endsWith(".txt"))continue;
            builder.append(emitted.getPartialPath()).append("\n");
        }
        builder.append("\n\n");

        builder.append("NETWORK:\n");
        for (String line : network) {
            builder.append(line + "\n");            
        }
        builder.append("\n\n");

        builder.append("FALLBACK:\n");

        EmittedArtifact manifest = emitString(logger, builder.toString(), "myapp.manifest");
        artifactset.add(manifest);
        System.out.println("MyApp OffLine Linker ended");
        return artifactset;
      }

}
```

Any help is well appreciated!

Comment: What options do you have set in your pom.xml for gwt-maven-plugin, and did the pom.xml change at all except to switch versions? I haven't experienced other linkers breaking like this...

Comment: Colin, looks like the api changed and I didn't pay the right attention, not sure.  But I got it to work overriding both signatures for method link, ArtifactSet link(TreeLogger logger, LinkerContext context, ArtifactSet artifacts, boolean onePermutation), which I didn't had on previous version and ArtifactSet link(TreeLogger logger, LinkerContext context, ArtifactSet artifacts)

Answer (score 0):

I finally had it working changing my AppManifast.java.  I noticed on current documentation that when using @Shardable annotation you have to override the other link method signature, so I added the following lines to the class:

```
@Override
public ArtifactSet link(TreeLogger logger, LinkerContext context, ArtifactSet artifacts, boolean onePermutation) throws UnableToCompleteException {
    return link(logger, context, artifacts);
}
```

It took me forever to find out...